# Weird arrow symbol at end of string in Angular Web App

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on a little chat app with Angular 4 where the users can communicate in real time through my website. They have a textarea where they input their message and send it by pressing the enter key. I console logged the message object that gets sent to the server and to my surprise the message string contains a weird arrow symbol at the end, even though I don't type it. Here is a screenshot:

https://gyazo.com/38f71029f2ae23afc01ee3f8f392c18c

It happens with empty and normal messages. Why is this happening?

Comment: It indicates that the content has multiple lines or line breaks.

Comment: The arrow indicates a newline character. I suspect somewhere in your code that gets added to the string.

Comment: Alright, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is line break symbol that indicates that the text has multiple lines.

*(answered by [Airwavezx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257670/weird-arrow-symbol-at-end-of-string-in-angular-web-app#comment79478847_46257670))*